# Increment the number of times an article has been read

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to increase the number of time article has been read.
Once someone opens an article it should be reflected in the database by incrementing number of reads by one. Simple.

Sending POST request to the server increments the number of reads by one. The article in question is supplied via URL parameter.

Doing it manually by typing the URL in a browser works as expected. So server side is not at fault.

My problems start with the javascript side of it or rather jquery. I hook the event to the article link. So every time a user clicks on the article link it increments the number of reads like so:

```
$('#list-articles .article-link').click(function(e){
  var oid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-oid').toString(); //Get the article id
  $.post( "/articles/viewed/" + oid );
});
```

Now this does not work! Number is not increased.

I don't prevent default action since I need the link to actually open and display the article.

Now if I put an alert right after the post like this:

```
$('#list-articles .article-link').click(function(e){
  var oid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-oid').toString(); //Get the article id
  $.post( "/articles/viewed/" + oid );
  alert(oid);
});
```

This variant works. After I dismiss the alert window, the number is incremented. Why is this so?? How can I fix this to actually work without the alert event present?

**UPDATE**

Thank you for helping to solve this. All answers are great and help one way or another. The only variant that works so far is disabling async on ajax call. It would be great if someone could elaborate on why switching the async mode off in ajax fixed it. So the post request in the original was never executed? If I was simply checking too early and the number increase was not visible upon page load, it should be still visible on the next page reload, right? SInce it wasn't updated on the database at all I assume that post was not run at all. Why is this so? I want to understand the issue so I  do't get into this problem again. Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering why you need to increment the read count through JavaScript. If you say it is updated when the article is loaded and your link redirects to the same link that you would type in manually, you are now incrementing it twice (once through JavaScript and once when you actually go to the article), aren't you?

Comment: you doing it the wrong way round, increment upon page load whn the page is being processed to be send or after the page has finished loaded for more accurate stats; or use piwik.

Comment: @ CompuChip They are different links. The route to the article is "/articles/:oid" and the control URL to increment the number is "/articles/viewed/:oid" The incrementing URL is just for background ajax process. So it is incremented just once upon clicking the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem could be due to `$.post` being asynchronous and you checking this too soon and try posting synchronously:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/articles/viewed/" + oid,
    async:false
});
```

Comment: That works. Cheers. Could you elaborate? I'd like to understand why. See the question update.

Comment: The reason for this is that your link actually unloads the page. Your browser then aborts the Ajax-request. In some cases it will go through because once it's sent, the server will process it. In other cases it will be aborted before it was sent and it will never arrive on the server. The correct thing to do is increment it when the page loaded and get rid of the Ajax-call altogether

Comment: @Kenneth Thanks. It is first time I've done this and I did not know the correct way. So I thought I'd figure it out on my own. Initially I tried to increment it on the server side up on page load but it did not do what I wanted. It would increment the number every time the page is reloaded which is obviously wrong. So I decided to hook the event to the click of the link with js. This seems to do what I want. How is it done correctly up on page load? Or do I need to create a separate question for this? Cheers.

Comment: If you do it on page-load there's really no way of checking whether it was a reload or a fresh request. It depends what you want to measure: if you're counting page views this is the correct behavior, if you're counting visitors you should probably leave a cookie and then check that cookie

Comment: @Kenneth No, it is not the visitors I need. All I need is to count how many times an article is read. I count it as read if it is clicked on and loaded but I don't want to increment the number of reads when you just reload the page. What is in my question is the best behaviour I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent default. Wait for the response from the server to say incrementing article reads by 1 was successful, then redirect to the article.

If it works with the alert in place it sounds like a race condition.

Comment: That is what I was thinking... kind of It sounds like Yair Nevet's answer above. But it does not work for some reason. Thanks.